# CodeIgniter l Unable to locate the model you have specified After Migrate from LocalHost

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

i am using CodeIgniter as FrameWork of my Website, and its working well on my Localhost Server ( Windows XAMPP ) but when i try to migrate it to any hosting it keep saying for the models(twitch, and database)

An Error Was Encountered

```
Unable to locate the model you have specified: Twitch_model
```

Here is The Model Start :

```
<?php
class database_model extends CI_Model {
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

The model filename is : `database_model,and twitch_model`

this is how i call them from the autoload file

```
$autoload['model'] = array('twitch_model' => 'twitch','database_model' => 'database');
```

Note That Erro just apear when i migrate from LocalHost to any other Webserver( current using digitalOcean) please help me, already spent 5 days trying to fix it, and tryed almost everything !

Comment: why you not call your model file directly from your controller?

Comment: Tryed it too, but seens not work, it gives the same error.

Comment: have you tried $this->load->model("your_model"); at the constructor of your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per TimBrownlaw's comment, I've updated this answer to reflect CI versions.

If using codeigniter 2 The file name should be lower case (like you show), 
application/models/twitch_model.php but if you are using codeigniter 3, the file name should start with an uppercase letter (Twitch_model.php). and the class name should be uppercase:

```
<?php
    class Twitch_model extends CI_Model {
```

If this doesn't help, you may be encountering a file permissions issue on the model file. The file/folder must be readable by the web server.

Comment: The version of Codeigniter has not been given... With Codeigniter 3 - ALL Class files names should be first letter Uppercase. ie application/models/Twitch_model.php. It is a change they made. This matters on Linux based systems where as Windows and Mac Systems are case insensitive,

Comment: This Worked, You Rock ! Please Mary My Daugther!

Comment: @PedroGS: If the solution worked for you then mark this one as accepted answer to close the thread..